# Stretching image

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper `div` that contains arbitrary content (I don't know its length). How can I put a background image that stretches its whole length since background-images doesn't stretch?

I've tried with a `div` containing a `img` tag. The div has a lover z-index that the rest of the content and has `position: absolute`. The problem is that the image is longer that the content and so it just makes it longer (the wrapper has `overflow: auto`).

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="image-wrapper" style="position: absolute"><img src="bg.jpg"></div>
    [.. OTHER CONTENT ..]
</div>
```

If I set the `div` and the image's width and height to 100%, it takes the window's height, not the wrapper's.

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`background-size` is available since CSS3:

```
#image {
  background-image: url("bg.png");
  background-size: auto;
}
```

`auto` is the default value and does not stretch the image.

You can set the width and height manually:

```
#image {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

or

```
#image {
  background-size: 500px 300px;
}
```

The alternative: `background-size: contain` and `background-size: cover`.

`contain` stretches the image so that the image is as big as possible but completely visible within the element, whereas `cover` stretches the image to 100% width, regardless if the image is cropped at the top and/or the bottom.

But the different browsers are not completely consistent when rendering backgrounds with these keywords.

Comment: `auto` is the default, `cover` & `contain` will stretch the BG image, but don't work in [IE<=8](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-background-properties/#bg11) and FF<4 needs the `-moz-` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use JavaScript, check out [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/2009/02/supersized-full-screen-backgroundslideshow-jquery-plugin/). It seems to work well for this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

you might also try html5 method on image.

```
#image-wrapper img {max-width: 100%}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with HTML5 - it's pure css. What you meant to say is that it's the approach used in responsive design to scale images to the container size.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to the styles for `#wrapper`.

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/